# What is the simplest way to remove all hyperlinks in a MS Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, hyperlink

What is the most simple way to remove all hyperlinks in an MS Word 2007 document?

I have been copying and pasting contents pages and would like to remove the automatically created hyperlinks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.

(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> selects all, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> [is the command to unlink a field](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/290938)).

Answer (score -2):

Try cutting and pasting into a new emails's CC box. After pasting it in there, copy it out of there and paste it into your word document, the Hyperlinks should be gone! I performed this on MS Word 2010 into an AOL email CC box and it worked like a charm.